# Change the format of the xml

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I am creating a webservice in .net :

**WebService :**

```
   public class ValidateWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]

        public List<string> ListAllArtists1()
        {
            List<string> all1 = new List<string>();

            all1.Add("Puneet");
            all1.Add("03/07/1988");
            all1.Add("Delhi");
            return all1;
        }

        }
}
```

and when I browse this webservice and invoke the method, ths will return me a list in xml format like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>   
- <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
  <string>Puneet</string>  
  <string>03/07/1988</string>  
  <string>Delhi</string>  
  </ArrayOfString>
```

My problem is the format of this xml. I want the xml format like this:

```
<Name>1</Name>  
<DOB>03/07/1988</DOB>  
<State>Delhi</State>
```

So that I can easily read the xml by the name of its nodes.

Please help.

Comment: If you want to write out a XML file/object you have to rely on XMLWriter by adapting the input format to what you want. Otherwise (if you just want to deal with this information internally at runtime), you don't even need to rely on XMLWriter. What is clear is that your input format is chaotic and thus the input parsing is the most important part here: what is the difference between <string>Puneet</string> and <string>03/07/1988</string>? The position? Just the value? How can the same node (<string>) be associated with so different inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want xml in such format, then return object instead of collection of strings:

```
public Artist GetArtist()
{
    Artist artist = new Artist();
    artist.Name = "Puneet";
    artist.DOB = "03/07/1988"; // consider DateTime type
    artist.State = "Delhi";

    return artist;
}
```

This will return serialized `Artist` instance:

```
<Artist>
    <Name>Puneet</Name>
    <DOB>03/07/1988</DOB>
    <State>Delhi</State>
</Artist>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be usefull, I will try this way and I am sure this will give me the results what I want.:)

Comment: @garvitgupta BTW you can use XmlSerializer to deserialize response into artist instance: `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Artist), "http://tempuri.org/"); var artist = (Artist)serializer.Deserialize(responseStream);` you only should provide your namespace instead of default one